# JQuery: Finding/Filtering on attributes within context

Tags: jquery, filter, find

I've been trying a few different ways to filter finding of specific nodes within my html.

Here is some example html:

```
<body>
    <div ui:component="component1"></div>
    <ul ui:component="component2"></ul>
    <article ui:component="component3"></article>
</body>
```

I've successfully been able to match items by doing a simple filter:

```
// returns div, ul, article
$('[ui\\:component]').each();
```

However, when I start filtering it based on a parent node, it starts to fail on me.  I've tried:

```
$('[ui\\:component]', $('body'));   // returns []
$('body').find('[ui\\:component]'); // returns []
$('body').filter('[ui\\:component]'); // returns []
$('body').find('*').filter('[ui\\:component]'); // returns []
```

What am I doing wrong here?  At first I thought it could be the ui namespace, but adding it to the html doc or the body doesn't seem to do anything of significance.  Help much appreciated

FULL SOURCE BELOW:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ui:component="component1"></div>
    <ul ui:component="component2"></ul>
    <article ui:component="component3"></article>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // returns div, ul, article
    console.log($('[ui\\:component]'));

    // these all return nada
    console.log($('[ui\\:component]', $('body')));
    console.log($('body').find('[ui\\:component]'));
    console.log($('body').filter('[ui\\:component]'));
    console.log($('body').find('*').filter('[ui\\:component]'));
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: NOTE: removing the namespace ui: seems to make it work.  But I don't like name collisions .......

Comment: When using Firefox 3.5, I was able to get it to work using `$("body *[ui\\:component]")`, however I didn't test any other browsers, so even though it's jQuery, I don't know if that will work everywhere.  And while I understand not wanting namespace collisions, browsers and js tend to not have great support for namespacing.

Comment: @Thomas - That would be similar to the code `$('[ui\\:component]')` that was working properly in the question. The selector works because it is using the native `querySelectorAll()` when available (that would include Firefox 3.5). But the `.find()` and `.filter()` don't work.

Comment: Thank you.  For now I've removed the namespace -- that is causing the incorrect find();

Comment: @patrick - Makes sense.  So most likely, these selectors would not work unless it was IE8+, FF3.5+ (according to quirksmode.org at least).

Comment: @Thomas - I'd guess that's the case, except that Safari/Chrome/Opera should be included among the working browsers, and I guess I wouldn't have much confidence in IE8 without testing. :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is because when you do:

```
$('[ui\\:component]')
```

...Sizzle is passing the selector to the browser's `document.querySelectorAll()` method (when available), effectively bypassing Sizzle.

Whereas when you do `.find()` or `.filter()`, Sizzle is being utilized.

So I'd guess that something in the selector is not supported by Sizzle, but is by `querySelectorAll()`. Perhaps the `:`.

I think you'll find that this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[ui\\:component]').length
```

and this:

```
$('[ui\\:component]').length
```

...will give you similar results

**EDIT:**

If it helps, a hyphen seems to work fine.

```
$('body').find('[ui-component]').length
```

HTML

```
<ul ui-component="component2"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to do this using jQuery is to write a custom selector:

```
$.expr[':'].nsattr = function(obj, ix, meta) {
    var attr = meta[3];

    return (obj.getAttribute(attr) ? true : false);
};
```

You can then call this with

```
$(document.body).find(':nsattr(ui:component)');
$(document.body).children().filter(':nsattr(ui:component)');
$(':nsattr(ui:component)', document.body);
```

Obviously this is not a neat way of doing this.  I suspect this is a bug with jQuery and it might be worth your reporting it as such.

Comment: I'm with you.  I filed a bug #7153

Comment: That looks good, although I'd probably use the native `getAttribute()` instead of creating a jQuery object for each element. You can also make it a little more concise like this: `return !!obj.getAttribute(attr);` instead of the `if()` statement. :o)

Comment: @patrick I have changed it to `hasAttribute()` -- good point.  This also means I can slim the return right down...

Comment: The `hasAttribute()` method would work, but for the not very surprising fact that [it isn't supported in IE6/7](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t115). :o(

Comment: Gah, had forgotten that `:-(`  A ternary is my verbose solution -- I find `!!` hard to read.  Thanks, patrick.

Comment: @Daniel, @lonesomeday - Just noting that [this issue is fixed](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/7153#comment:1) in the [soon to be released `1.4.3`](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/10/jquery-1-4-3-release-candidate-1-released/). Tested it against `rc1`, and indeed it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<div id="component"></div>` instead..

Comment: Not looking to make it an id.  I'm looking to assign functionality to specific items based on their ui:component tag.